# An error in my database when i copy my website in an other host

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database

I copied my website from my linux server to windows server (wamp). I export the database and i import it to my windows server.When i try to access my magento site i have this error.

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.index_process' doesn't exist

what this problem ?

Comment: Well...does the table exist? Make sure that the import is finished. Check if you have all the tables. Also, next time use the Magento database back-up tool. (system->tools->backup)

Comment: When importing, make sure you don't load Magento (it will create all sorts of tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the following:

- Has your database been fully imported? Does the table count match with the database on your linux server?
- Was there an error during import?
- Check your var/report folder and var/log/system.log and exception.log for further error messages.
- Did you call the magento website during import? You should not and you might set a maintenance site during import.
- Try to run the reindexing from command line.
- Delete cache files.

Answer (score 0):

Amirov
First i'd try to run the reindexer.php from the command line on the new linux server.
If that doesn't work or has a similar error, Given that you said 'WAMP' i suspect you'll be used to looking at phpmyadmin, so.. from your WAMP server go to phpmyadmin, selecet your database, click export, find the option to export the database schema, it might be called 'structure' on the new phpmyadmin in anycase export without the 'data', open it up in a text editor find the table you need and create it on your linux server by pasting the text into the new linux server phpmyadmin.

Then try running the reindexer.php from the command line on the new linux server again.

If you get no help from either of the above, download and place the magento database repair tool on your WAMP server, and use this as the reference database.